# how to get url from to long string (iframe) ios swift

Tags: ios, string, swift

how to get url from to long string in my app i am getting this string from server

```
"content" = "<p><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/HJ3EIbhwx2w\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe></p>\n"
```

So now I want to https://www.youtube.com/embed/HJ3EIbhwx2w out of string. How can I do this in swift?

Comment: you can load this directly on webview. no need to get url

Comment: but the thing is its have width = 560 but i want to replace it with 360@NitinGohel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok finally i had done it by NSScanner
here is my code

```
func cutout(us:String)
{


    let scanner = NSScanner(string:us)
    var scanned: NSString?

    if scanner.scanUpToString("://", intoString:nil) {
        scanner.scanString("://", intoString:nil)
        if scanner.scanUpToString("width", intoString:&scanned) {
            let result: String = scanned as! String
            print("result: \(result)")
            urlStringmy = result// result: google
            stringcutter()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd change the server to send the appropriate information.

Otherwise, you could use a regular expression, or an `NSScanner` to find the URL and extract it. This approach could also work to change the width number instead of extracting the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
webView .loadHTMLString("<style>img,iframe{width: 100%;}</style>" + (postToDisplay?.postPostContent)!, baseURL: nil)
```

`postToDisplay?.postPostContent` is your actual other content